# Map to form key/value pair in spark implementation in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have a dataset which I will read from file as,

```
1 2 3 4 5:9:3 2 1 2 1
2 3 5:4:1 2 1
4 5:3:1 2
```

I am trying to split these with each line and then create a key/value with the left part of `colon` with corresponding right part of `colon`. For example, in the first line, `1` is mapped with `3` to become `(1,3)` and `2` is mapped with `2` to become `(2,2)`. Similarly, there will be `(3,1), (4,2), (5,1)` for the first line. Similarly, it should generate for 2nd line and 3rd line.

I have tried to split each line so far with map function and then I am trying to create the tuple by mapping each of the left part items with the corresponding right part value.

Code so far:

```
   JavaRDD<List<String>> transactions = data.map(
                new Function<String, List<String>>() {
                    public List<String> call(String line) {
                        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                        return Arrays.asList(parts);
                    }
                }
        );

   JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = transactions.mapToPair(
                new PairFunction<List<String>, String, Integer>() {
                    public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(List<String> w) {

                        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>....;
                    }
                });
```

I am struck on the return part. Is there any way that I get all the key/value pairs?

PS: I am new to apache spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flatmap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html) for a relatively more elegant solution:

```
val res = dataset.flatMap(line => {
    val f = line.split(":", -1) //taking care of the empty values with -1
    val keys = f(0).split(" ", -1)
    val values = f(2).split(" ", -1)
    keys.zip(values) //List[(String, String)], (key, value) pairs for a line
})

res.collect.map(println)

(1,3)
(2,2)
(3,1)
(4,2)
(5,1)
(2,1)
(3,2)
(5,1)
(4,1)
(5,2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :) Now need to convert this scala code into Java.